# SwiftUI Picker on item reselect

Tags: swiftui

Is there a way to have a `Picker` view fire some event when the current selection has been *reselected*? I know on Android, for example, tab layouts have functions for both tab change and tab reselect.  The idea is that I'd like to refetch some data even if the user selects an item they are already on.

I've tried the `selection` arg in the `Picker` view, as well as `onChange`, but they only fire when the value actually changes.

```
func onPress(_ i: Int) {
  print("onPress fired \(i)")
}

var body: some View {
  Picker("Page", selection: $tab.onChange(onPress)) {
    ...
  }.onChange(of: selected, perform: { selected in
    print("onChange fired \(selected)")
  })
}
```

I also tried adding a simultaneous gesture to both the `Picker` and the elements inside it, but that didn't work either.

```
func onPress(_ i: Int) {
  print("onPress fired \(i)")
}

var body: some View {
  Picker("Page", selection: $tab.onChange(onPress)) {
    ...
  }.simultaneousGesture(
    TapGesture().onEnded { _ in print("gesture fired") }
  )
}
```

I suppose I could just spin up my own Picker component but I'd rather not do that if I can continue to use the one provided.  Would appreciate any ideas, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using just onTapGesture instead of simultaneousGesture? I was able to get that to print in playgrounds without any impact to the picker.

Comment: @Shawn if I add that to the `Picker` itself then it blocks the actual picking functionality.  And if I add it to item inside the `Picker` then the tap gesture is blocked by the `Picker`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by using a `DragGesture` on the `Picker`. This interferes with the `Picker`'s functionality, so you'll have set the selection manually from this gesture, which requires a bit of math. But as long as you know how many items are in the `Picker` and how much horizontal space it takes up, it works fine.

The only caveat is you now lose the ability to drag the `Picker` from side to side. But that's a small price to pay to get this working.

```
func onPress(_ i: Int) {
  print("onPress fired \(i)")
  tab = i
}

var body: some View {
  Picker("Page", selection: $tab.onChange(onPress)) {
    ...
  }.gesture(
    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local)
      .onEnded { position in
        let x = position.location.x
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width

        // Assumes picker is 100% width minus some constant padding
        let bounds = screenWidth - PADDING_AROUND_PICKER
        let itemWidth = bounds / NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_IN_PICKER
        let cell = Int(x / itemWidth)
        
        onPress(cell)
      }
  )
}
```